# Generate and download Pdf file using Rails 3

Tags: ruby, pdf, ruby-on-rails-3.2, prawn

I have a problem in my code.I need when user will click on download link provided on index page the PDF file will generate and at the same time it will download using Rails 3.I am using prawn gem for generating the PDF.but i can not know what should be the route path in link_to tag in rails.Please check me following code.

> products/index.html.erb:

```
<h1>Choose the option</h1>
<p>
    <%= link_to "new input",products_new_path %>
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
       <th>Product name</th>
       <th>Product Catagory</th>
    </tr>
    <% @product.each do |p| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= p.p_name %></td>
        <td><%= p.p_catagory %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
<%= link_to "Download Pdf" %>
```

> controller/products_controller.rb:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @product=Product.all
        require "prawn/table"
        require "prawn"
        Prawn::Document.generate("test.pdf") do |pdf|
            table_data = Array.new
            table_data << ["Product name", "Product category"]
            @product.each do |p|
                table_data << [p.p_name, p.p_catagory]
            end
            pdf.table(table_data, :width => 500, :cell_style => { :inline_format => true })
        end
    end
    def new
        @product=Product.new
    end
    def create
        @product=Product.new(params[:product])
        if @product.save
            flash[:notice]="Data submitted"
            flash[:color]="valid"
            redirect_to :action => "index"
        else
            flash[:alert]="Data could not finish"
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            render 'new'
        end
    end
end
```

> Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.19'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
gem 'prawn', '~> 1.3.0'
gem 'prawn-table', '~> 0.2.1'
```

> routes.rb:

```
Generate::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => "products#index"
  get "products/new" => "products#new"
  post "products/create" => "products#create"

end
```

My requirement is when user will click on `"Download pdf"` link the html table value will convert into pdf and it will generate for take print out and download as well.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: You need to have a controller action that responds with the PDF data using `send_data` or `send_file`. Your `link_to` will use the route that corresponds to that controller action. That controller action will probably also be the place you want to put your PDF-generation logic as well.

Comment: @ Jordan : Can you please say here how can i apply your logic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

products/index.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to "Download_pdf", download_pdf_path(:format => 'pdf') %>
```

Gemfile :

```
gem 'prawn'
gem 'prawn-table'
```

routes.rb, Add following route:

```
get "products/download_pdf" => "products#download_pdf", :as => 'download_pdf'
```

Do bundle install.

products_controller.rb

```
require "prawn"
  require "prawn/table"

      def download_pdf
        @product = Product.all
        respond_to do |format|
          format.pdf do
            pdf = Prawn::Document.new
            table_data = Array.new
            table_data << ["Product name", "Product category"]
            @product.each do |p|
                table_data << [p.p_name, p.p_catagory]
            end
            pdf.table(table_data, :width => 500, :cell_style => { :inline_format => true })
            send_data pdf.render, filename: 'test.pdf', type: 'application/pdf', :disposition => 'inline'
          end
        end
      end
```

This will generate your pdf.

Comment: @ user123 : I did as per you .I put last bunch of code inside download_pdf method in controller page.But after click on that link no pdf file is generating.

Comment: @ user123 :Thanks now its working.But another one thing,Now after clicking on that link its downloading,Can I open this when user clicked on link for take printout purpose.

Comment: add :disposition => 'inline' option as follows:

send_data pdf.render, filename: 'test.pdf', type: 'application/pdf', :disposition => 'inline'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78666/discussion-between-user123-and-satya).

Comment: @ user123 : i have another one doubt.Suppose i have one customize table which is present inside the index.html.erb.I want to add these product values inside that table.In this case it is displaying the simple table.So how can i add these value in that table and generate the Pdf file.

Comment: If you want to use index.html.erb then you should use wicked_pdf gem instead.

Comment: Shown in the simplest way possible, best ever , thank you @VrushaliPawar